# Process Large Data with PHP API

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to process large data by calling a MySQL and PHP API from JavaScript. I send about 10000 numbers every 10 seconds. My API is checking last value of that number and, if there are any changes in it, it adds one new entry for that number.

For example, I have a list of 10,000 numbers stored in the database table. When I send data using API, it gets the last value of each number and if the last value is 0 and new value is 1, then it will store number with value 1.

It's working fine but it's really slow. I want to improve the speed of processing my data. I know it depends on my server, but I think my logic for processing this data could also be improved. Please check my API and let me know if you see a way to improve it.

MyAPI.PHP

```
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName);
if($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$number = $_GET["number"];
$status = $_GET["status"];
$sql = "SELECT number_status FROM number_status WHERE number = '$number' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$lastStatus = -1;
if($result) {
    $lastStatus = $result->fetch_row()[0];
}
if($lastStatus != $status) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO number_status (number, number_status) VALUES ('$number', $status)";
    $conn->query($sql);
    $response["status"] = 1;
}
else {
    $response["status"] = 0;
}
$response["error"] = $conn->error;
echo $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($response) . ")";
```

Comment: sounds incredibly inefficient, but to few details to suggest an alternative

Comment: Well you can optimize your script in many ways. First of all, using session, you can store `number_status` in session variable, so no need of `SELECT` query to fetch last record. Also, use `mysql_connect` only if session is destroyed. And, use prepared statement, they are highly efficient is such scenario.